# Library/Function to tell the user how secure their password is?

Tags: c#, security

I need to be able to tell the user if their password is strong or weak (or in between). Is there a library or a function that already does this?

If there isn't, what would be the best approach to determining if a password is secure or not?

Comment: is this for ASP.NET, Forms, WPF, Silverlight or Command Line?

Comment: this is for winforms, and possibly later, cli. It's also probably going to run under mono, but that's not a requirement yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to check the strength of a password?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75057/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-the-strength-of-a-password)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[KeePass](http://keepass.info/) has a password strength function.  You can download the source zip file from [here](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/keepass/KeePass-2.10-Source.zip).  The file you are looking for is called QualityEstimation in KeePassLib.Cryptography.

Answer (score 2):

You can check out some articles on CodeProject.
1) http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/PasswordStrengh.aspx
2) http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/passworddialog.aspx

A simple approach is to evaluate some regular expressions to check if it contains uppercase and lowercase letters, numbers, special symbols and the length of the password.