# Java Regular Expression with Either Uppercase or Lowercase, but not both

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

I am working on an expression for a password, where the validation should contain

1. must contains letters with numbers or symbols( NOT letters, numbers and symbols)
2. Uppercase or Lowercase( NOT a combination of both)
3. Min length of password is 8

based on the inputs provided by Mena, i have updated my expression to

```
String patternChar = "^[a-z&&[^A-Z]]+|[A-Z&&[^a-z]]+$";
String patternNumber = "^[a-zA-Z0-9&&[\\S]]+|[a-zA-Z\\S&&[^0-9]]+$";
```

1. PatternChar works fine for only Upper or Lower Case.
2. PatternNumber does work if i combine PatternChar with numbers or symbols.

here symbol means all `UTF8` or unicode characters like e.g. `£$%^`

Thanks for your help.

but has problems.

Regards
Ram

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364345/regexp-for-password

Comment: You want a single RegEx or two different RegEx ?

Comment: need 2 regex. how can i provide support for  UTF8 chars. As Java by default provide ascii support.