# Java creating a complex regular expression for password validation

Tags: java, regex

I have a regular expression right now that enforces a requirement on a password in my Java application.

I want to now modify this expression so it reflects this policy:

at least 7 characters
contains characters in three or more of the following character classes:

**(a-z), (A-Z), (0-9), (@#$,. )**

and the character at the beginning or end do not count towards its character class.

Is this too complex for a regular expression? If not, how can I modify my existing to adhere to the new one?

Thanks

Here is my current:

```
String credPattern = "((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%,.]).{7,})";
pattern = Pattern.compile(credPattern);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(pw);
```

Comment: Obligatory xkcd comic : https://xkcd.com/936/

Comment: If you're having issues creating the regex, you'll have some more when you'll need to update it. I suggest you use a library for that. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200292/password-strength-checking-library

Comment: Why use a regex when a trivial piece if Java code can perform the same validation, while being simpler to read, and maintain?

Comment: @Malt that is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this pattern will apply all four character class conditions, beginning/end and minimum character count requirement:

```
^.(?=.*[a-z].)(?=.*[A-Z].)(?=.*[0-9].)(?=.*[@#$,.].).{6,}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/286)
what you want to do is break it into four Regex patterns like so

```
^.(?=.*[a-z].)(?=.*[A-Z].)(?=.*[0-9].).{6,}$    
^.(?=.*[a-z].)(?=.*[A-Z].)(?=.*[@#$,.].).{6,}$  
^.(?=.*[a-z].)(?=.*[0-9].)(?=.*[@#$,.].).{6,}$  
^.(?=.*[A-Z].)(?=.*[0-9].)(?=.*[@#$,.].).{6,}$
```

run each one and count the number of matches using your scripting language, if greater than 3 it's a success.
note: white spaces are allowed per your original pattern.