# Regex for Password validation first and last letter cannot have a symbol

Tags: java, regex

I need a regexp for password validation.
Validation rules-

- Password is case sensitive
- Must be no more than 50 characters long
- Must include at least 1 number
- Must have at least 1 symbol (non letter or number) character
- The first character can not be a symbol (non letter or number)
- The last character can not be a symbol (non letter or number)
- Must not repeat any character sequentially more than 2 times
- Must have at least 1 lowercase letter
- Must have at least 1 uppercase letter
- Must be at least 8 characters long

So far I have this -

```
 "^(?!.*(.)\\1{2})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9]). 
        {8,50}$"
```

It doesn't work for the first and last character cannot be a symbol.

I have tried

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9](?!.*(.)\1{2})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9]).{6,48}[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

but it is not working as well.Please help me out.

Comment: Java != Javascript

Comment: Why do you need a (single) regex? Can't you validate the conditions separately?

Comment: @shmosel I need to have a single regex for the project I am working on

Comment: give the test cases too

Comment: @I'-'I For example Default$123 will not work for second regex.For first regex it will allow any symbol as first and last character.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the approach. Your solution of having just one huge extensible regex doesn't conform Java.
I'd suggest you think about building a library that can accept different rules and combine them. This will be much easier to test, it will be much more understandable for new people, less error-prone and easily extensible unlike the regex of the kind you are showing.

This discussed here:
[Password strength checking library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200292/password-strength-checking-library)
and suggested http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/edu.vt.middleware/vt-password

Another option is here: https://github.com/larcki/validly
So the code would look like that:

```
import static com.validly.FailFastValidator.*;

public class Validator {

    public void validate(String input) throws ValidationErrorException {
        valid(input)
            .mustNotBeNull("It's null")
            .lengthMustBeAtLeast(2, "It's too short")
            .mustStartWith("Hello", "It doesn't start properly")
            .must(s -> myOwnRule(s), "It doesn't match my own rule");
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Each restriction can be a look ahead:

```
^(?=.*\d).{8,50}
```

- (irrelevant) Password is case sensitive
- `.{8,50}` Must be no more than 50 characters long and Must be at least 8 characters long
- `(?=.*\d)` Must include at least 1 number
- `(?=.*(\W|_))` Must have at least 1 symbol (non letter or number) character
- `[^\W_]` The first character can not be a symbol (non letter or number)
- `[^\W_]` The last character can not be a symbol (non letter or number)
- `(?!.*(.)\1)` Must not repeat any character sequentially more than 2 times
- `(?=.*[a-z])` Must have at least 1 lowercase letter
- `(?=.*[A-Z])` Must have at least 1 uppercase letter

Putting it all together:

```
^(?!.*(.)\1)(?=.*\d)(?=.*(\W|_))(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[^\W_].{6,48}[^\W_]$
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/n2bU3a8BGL).