# Runtime warning when calculaing entropy

Tags: python, quantitative-finance

There is a runtime warning for my entropy function in my script. I don't understand why it is running this error.

I thought I forgot to import the numpy library. However, when I run the script, it says that the issue is with the log base 2. I don't really know how to fix this. Any tips?

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

# Retrieve the stock data
ticker = yf.Ticker("ES=F")
df = ticker.history(interval="2m", period="60d")

# Calculate the order flow imbalance
df["order_flow_imbalance"] = df["Volume"]
df.loc[df["Close"] > df["Open"], "order_flow_imbalance"] *= -1

# Calculate the entropy
total_orders = df["order_flow_imbalance"].sum()
p_buy = df.loc[df["order_flow_imbalance"] > 0, 
"order_flow_imbalance"].sum() / total_orders
p_sell = df.loc[df["order_flow_imbalance"] < 0, 
"order_flow_imbalance"].sum() / total_orders
entropy = -p_buy * np.log2(p_buy) - p_sell * np.log2(p_sell)
df["entropy"] = entropy

# Calculate the returns
df["returns"] = (df["Close"] - df["Open"]) / df["Open"]

# Filter the data
df = df[df["order_flow_imbalance"] > 100000]

# Plot the data
sns.scatterplot(x="returns", y="entropy", data=df)
sns.regplot(x="returns", y="entropy", data=df)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can't evaluate your problem without code input. Provide code sample and error trace to understand your issue.

Comment: just added the code now, my apologies

Comment: Post the error.

Comment: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log2
  entropy = -p_buy * np.log2(p_buy) - p_sell * np.log2(p_sell)

Answer (score 0):

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log2 entropy = -p_buy * np.log2(p_buy) - p_sell * np.log2(p_sell)
```

You are getting this error because values passed to log scale are in negative.
p_buy = -552.6374.

Place a check to modify values to be greater than 0 before passing them to log scale.

Comment: How would I do that exactly? Thank you for answering my question!

Comment: @TayrohnJackson, while debugging I got p_buy value in negative. So first rule of thumb, log scales don't accept negative values, it should be > 0. To avoid this consider `abs(p_buy)` and `abs(p_sell)`, I can't be sure if it satisfies your requirement.

Comment: I believe you solved my negative value problem, however, I think it highlighted another problem. I am getting a syntax error for the entropy dataframe

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: Input In [14]
    df["entropy"] = entropy
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: df is a dataframe, you are assigning a float value to df column. Logic is not correct, check this for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49685591/how-to-find-the-entropy-of-each-column-of-data-set-by-python