# How to calculate the entropy rate of a numpy ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy

For a random variable sequence, first I convert it to a numpy ndarray. Then i want to calculate the [entropy rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_rate)? Have good ways to do it? not entropy.

Besides, the variable generated by model is random. To simply, I create a list, then, convert it to a numpy ndarray.

```
import numpy as np
list_num = [4,6,2,8,1,0,10,2,9]
a = np.asarray(list_num)
a.shape
#compute the extropy rate of a
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest way to compute entropy in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15450192/fastest-way-to-compute-entropy-in-python)

Comment: can you elaborate how your entropy is defined?

Comment: @Bazingaa my question is to compute entropy rate, not entropy.

Comment: @PZY: You will have to include the definition of entropy then

Comment: @adrtam, the definition of entropy rate is [entropy rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_rate)

Comment: @PZY without knowing which model you generate 4, 6, 2, ..., it is impossible to answer.

Comment: @adrtam The variable generated by model is random. To simply, I create a list, then, convert it to a numpy ndarray.

Comment: try pyinform library