# How to calculate entropy from frequency table?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, entropy

I have data on a bunch of names (> 10 million) and their associated counts.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


data = {
    "Name": ['Sara', 'John', 'Mark', 'Peter', 'Kate'],
    "Count": [20, 10, 5, 2, 5],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

```
    Name  Count
0   Sara     20
1   John     10
2   Mark      5
3  Peter      2
4   Kate      5
```

I want to compute the entropy of the `Count` column WITHOUT expanding the data to be like `[Sara, Sara, Sara,...,Kate, Kate, Kate]` because there are just too many observations for that.

**How would I compute entropy of `Count`** without expanding the data?

Comment: Define Entropy.

Comment: Isn't entropy easily calculated based upon the counts by converting them to bin probabilities (each count divided by total count), and summing -pi*log(pi) (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15450192/fastest-way-to-compute-entropy-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the dataframe is containing the value counts for each name, you can directly feed a `Series` of counts to [`scipy.stats.entropy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.entropy.html):

```
from scipy.stats import entropy

entropy(df.set_index('Name').squeeze())
# 1.3466893828909594
```

---

As @nils mentions, if what you want is the binary entropy you can set `base=2`

Comment: OP is most likely looking for the Shannon entropy, so you need to set the kwarg `base=2`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compute de Shannon's entropy  `H = -Sum[ P(xi) * log2( P(xi)) ]`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math


data = {
    "Name": ['Sara', 'John', 'Mark', 'Peter', 'Kate'],
    "Count": [20, 10, 5, 2, 5],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['prob'] = df['Count']/df['Count'].sum()
df['log'] = df.apply(lambda x: math.log(x['prob'],2),axis=1)
df['prod'] = df['prob']*df['log']

print('Entropy: ', -df['prod'].sum())
```

Comment: There is no need for `apply()` and `math.log()`, but instead you can do it all vectorized.