# Regex Python pattern

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a program that uses regular expressions to make sure the password string it is passed is strong. A strong password is defined as one that is at least eight characters long, contains both uppercase and lowercase characters, and has at least one digit. So far, I have the following code. I have spent hours tinkering the regular expression, however I cant make it so that it will pass. Each time I make a change, it seems a strong password gets marked as weak, or a weak as strong. Any idea how I can improve this?

```
import re


pass2Regex = re.compile(r'''
    \d*
    [a-zA-Z]*
    \d*
    [a-zA-Z]*
    ''',re.VERBOSE)


text = raw_input("enter your password\n")
if len(text) >= 8:
    search = pass2Regex.findall(text)
    if text in search:
        print "%s is a strong password" % (text)
    else:
        print "%s is a weak password" % (text)
else:
    print "%s is a weak password" % (text)
```

For example, right now if the password were "231242441", it would be marked as a strong password even though there are no letters. Furthermore, When I try a + instead of a * it will only accept passwords that start with a digit, etc..

Thanks for the help

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/75149/3928184

Comment: Also, see [*Regex for Password Must be contain at least 8 characters, least 1 number and both lower and uppercase letters and special characters*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605150/regex-for-password-must-be-contain-at-least-8-characters-least-1-number-and-bot). Remove the "special characters" conditions and you have your answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew's suggestion is even more useful than mine

Comment: Relevant regex from that answer: `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{8,}$` Another way to write that last part is `[^\W_]{8,}`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Although that code is pretty helpful, it's sort of confusing. I appreciate the answer, but any chance you mind helping me with my version of the code? No worries if not.

Comment: Here is the regex for your logic: http://ideone.com/o6a4N7

Comment: To be honest, your expression would even validate an empty string :)

Comment: Before trying to write a regex to check a "strong password", take the time to search and ask you what is a "strong password".

Comment: Please consider changing your title to "Python regex for strong password" or similar.  It will help others with the same problem find your question easier than "Python regex pattern"

Answer (score 1):

You have all of python to work with, so don't limit yourself to a single regexp. Write one regexp for each condition that the password must satisfy. "Contains uppercase"? Trivial. "Lowercase"? Also trivial. "At least one digit"? No problem. "At least 8 characters long"? You don't even need a regexp.

You can cascade the tests, combine a series of tests with `and`, or put the tests in a list and apply them in one go like this:

```
tests = [ "[A-Z]", "[a-z]", r"\d", ".{8}" ]
if all(re.search(pat, text) for pat in tests):
    print("It's a strong password")
```

Save your hours of effort for the next step.

Comment: Why should he if he can have it all at once?

Comment: Because any single-regexp "solution", even yours, will be far less readable, verifiable or extensible (i.e., maintainable) than splitting it up.

Comment: I agree with you that most regex solutions suffer from not being written in verbose mode - however, if you **do add** comments (and this is what I usually do), I think they are often more straight-forward than looking up every function's parameter - after all it's a matter of taste, I guess :)

Comment: Verbose mode is nice, but you've still got a regexp where all the work is done in multiple overlapping lookaheads that don't even use non-greedy wildcards. Thanks but I'll pass. And comments are not verification-- they can be incorrect.

Comment: @Jan I love regex.  But fewer people can write/maintain a regex than can understand/update/maintain Python string methods.  If a simpler, clearer, more easily maintained way is available, choose it.

Comment: @Akshit, what makes you think this not an answer? The answer is "split it up into several regexps and you can have a very simple solution."

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, this is a typical use-case for lookarounds (lookaheads in this situation).
A lookahead **looks ahead without consuming characters** (this is an assertion).
Broken down to your needs:

> A strong password is defined as one that is at least eight characters
>   long, contains both uppercase and lowercase characters, and has at
>   least one digit.

```
^                    # anchors the expression to the beginning
    (?=[^a-z]*[a-z]) # not lowercase, followed by lowercase
    (?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z]) # not UPPERCASE, followed by UPPERCASE
    (?=\D*\d)        # not a digit, followed by a digit
    .{8,}            # at least 8 characters long
$                    # anchor the expression to the end
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/lU9zU9/1).

---

So for your code snippet this would be:

```
import re
pass2Regex = re.compile(r"""
    ^                    # anchors the expression to the beginning
        (?=[^a-z]*[a-z]) # not lowercase, followed by lowercase
        (?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z]) # not UPPERCASE, followed by UPPERCASE
        (?=\D*\d)        # not a digit, followed by a digit
        .{8,}            # at least 8 characters long
    $                    # anchor the expression to the end
""", re.VERBOSE)

password = "WeaK1234"
password2 = "strong?"

if pass2Regex.search(password):
    print "Strong!"

if pass2Regex.search(password2):
    print "Strong!"
```

Comment: I dont really understand your comments or what the anchors do.. Do you mind explaining in other words? Thanks!

Comment: OP code actually already checks the string length, you needn't add `{8,}` at the end. `+` is enough :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Wasn't aware of that, thanks.

Comment: @brianhalperin: `^` and `$` make sure to match at the start and end of the string, respectively.